# Why I can't print objects with .forEach()?

Tags: java, list, stream

I am trying to use streams to group my objects by nationality and print them out. 
But it says : "Cannot resolve method 'println"

```
class Person {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String nationality;

public static  void groupByNationality(List<Person> people) {
     people
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getNationality))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getNationality))` is a terminal operation that returns a `Map<String,List<Person>>`.

`Map`'s `forEach` requires a `BiConsumer<? super K, ? super V> action` argument, which requires a method with two arguments. This doesn't conform with the signature of `System.out::println` (all the `println` methods have a single argument).

You could change

```
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

to

```
.forEach((key,value)->System.out.println (key + ":" + value));
```

Comment: Oh I got it now, could you please help me where I can find a documentation, to how to read instructions like this : BiConsumer<? super K, ? super V> action because I don't really understand those

Comment: Look at the Javadoc of `BiConsumer`. You'll see that it has a `void accept(T t, U u)` method, which takes two arguments. @DanE

Comment: also, why do I get this strange output ? : 'Serbian:[sample.Person@6acbcfc0]
Norwegian:[sample.Person@5f184fc6, sample.Person@3feba861]'

Comment: @DanE You'll have to override `toString()` of `Person` class if you want more meaningful output.